# How do I control the mesh extrusion?

Tags: 3d-view

So a got a some mesh here:
[image]
And when i click E to extrude it doesn't do it and i get some sort of a division:
[image]
And setting up Origin to Geometry makes the plane dissapear. Any help?
Moving the object with G also makes it dissapear.

Comment: I do not understand your use of the word division.  Perhaps others do.  How did you create this mesh? The image is difficult to read.  Or you just might see a proposed answer.

Comment: Please upload your .blend here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mesh does not appear to be a major time investment thus I suggest

- Delete the mesh.  This may delete a one time mistake.
- Create a new mesh
- Fresh Start
- Try to work with the new mesh

Deleting defective work that has a low time investment and creating a new work can save time.  If you have the same defect many times in a row and you report this then we need a different approach.

Comment: Re done the mesh and it works now. Not sure what the problem was, i did some Subdivision smoothing before trying to extrude. Might've been that.